# Допустимость вопросов на транслите

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, очередь-проверок, причины-закрытия

Допустимы ли вопросы, написанные транслитом?

[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/921597/213987):

> Xochu nauchitsya programuvati na C++. Z chego nachati?

Корректно ли будет закрывать подобные вопросы с формулировкой:

> Вопрос закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято
>   задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на
>   русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

PS Да-да, я понимаю, что данный конкретный вопрос можно закрыть и по другой формулировке, что я и сделал — но интересует именно случай, если бы был задан вполне корректный, скажем, каким-нибудь участником из Мюнхена, у которого вдруг не оказалось бы под рукой русской клавиатуры.

Comment: А просто перевести - не вариант?

Comment: @Qwertiy а вдруг ТС понимает только транслит?

Comment: @älёxölüt дети индиго :D

Comment: Хорошо хоть не удавовский.

Comment: У меня! У меня нет под рукой русской клавиатуры. И никогда не будет (. https://translit.net/

Comment: Я бы предположил, что если человек имеет под руками клавиатуру только с латиницей, то вероятнее всего у него достаточный уровень знаний чтобы написать вопрос на более активной версии so, чем измудряться с транслитом или переводом его в читабельный русский :D

Answer (score 19):

Такие вопросы (и сообщения в целом) не являются допустимыми и их следует закрывать как требующие правки. Если у кого-то вдруг возникло непреодолимое желание написать по-русски, но неожиданно не оказалось под рукой русской клавиатуры, то я вижу как минимум пару возможных вариантов написать текст адекватно:

- включить экранную клавиатуру с нужной раскладкой и натыкать сообщение
- настроить и переключить раскладку текущей аппаратной клавиатуры и просто набрать текст "слепым методом"

В итоге текст получится такой же как и при наличии полноценной аппаратной клавиатуры с нужными кнопками. Хотя возможно у кого-то такой ввод потребует чуть больше времени.

Чтобы понять, что писать транслитом не стоит, достаточно рассмотреть ситуацию с другой стороны - представить появление на enSO текстов, написанных на кириллице.

Ай вуд лайк ту эск ю эбаут юсинг оф нон Латин чарактерс он инглишь лангуэйдж сайтс.

Comment: Угу, "лет ми спик фром май харт".

Comment: Если вопрос объемный, то писать экранной - ужас(у меня некоторое время был ноутбук без клавы), а по слепому не все могут.  попросить Тогда третий вариант - написать, что понимаешь, что вопрос противоречит правилам, написать почему не можешь писать латиницей, и попросить перевести на русский правкой.

Comment: @Anton238, такой вариант приемлем, но только если пользователь уже освоился на сайте достаточно, чтобы понять, что: 1) здесь используется *только русский язык*; 2) существует такая вещь как *правка*. Новичок вряд ли будет беспокоиться по поводу перевода. Создаст вопрос на транслите и будет ждать: если помогли (и перевели вопрос) - хорошо; не помогли - новичок создаст еще вопрос. Разумеется, на транслите.

Comment: @Dima это да, к сожалению.

Answer (score 10):

1. **Все программы** > **Стандартные** > **Специальные возможности** > **Экранная клавиатура**
2. Есть сервисы для перевода транслита в нормальный язык.
3. Если человеку настолько лень следовать правилам и писать на русском, то да, нужно закрывать.

Comment: П.1 не всегда полезен. Если на общественном компе не стоит поддержка русс. клавиатуры, а в вопросе скорее всего этот случай, то там будут те же лат. буквы.

Comment: @0xdb несколько странный сценарий: возникла проблема по программированию, задал вопрос с общественного компьютера. Если ТС занимается за этим же компом, то, имхо, наличие языков устраивает.

Comment: Хмм, общественный надо было в кавычки заключить. Например, у меня та же ситуация, ноут дали на выполнение проекта, там нет русс. клавы и пользуюсь пунктом 2. PS думаю всё таки у автора не было злого умысла писать латинкой.

Comment: @0xdb никто и не говорит, что злонамеренно.

Comment: Это было PS. Непонятно только, почему п.1 собственно первый и выделен жирным, если он в 99% случаев не может быть использован.

Comment: @0xdb я когда указываю настройки/пути таким образом, всегда выделяю. Тут особого умысла и цели акцентировать внимание на этот пункт не было )